# Right Click on marker - Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, right-click

I've been trying to get a right click working on my markers but so far it seems that the event just isn't fired. As a workaround I'm currently detecting a right click on the map and then finding the nearest marker and triggering the right click method - obviously thats not great.

According to the docs, markers do have a right click event so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', handleRightClick)
```

doesn't work but

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', handleRightClick)
```

works fine. As does:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', handleRightClick)
```

I'm also using a custom marker plugin called markerWithLabel - http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/reference.html - I thought I'd cracked it when I discovered that this didn't add an event listener for the right click but even when I added one in myself, still no luck. I added this at line 257:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.eventDiv_, "rightclick", function(e) {
    if (me.marker_.getClickable()) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "rightclick", e);
        cAbortEvent(e);
    }
})
```

Has anyone had similar issues or found better workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your handleRightClick function do?

Comment: at the moment? It just shows an alert. just trying to prove its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you had your map object and it's called globalmap (you made as a new google.maps.Map)

This will add a marker on maps' center:

```
var newmarker=new google.maps.Marker({map:globalmap, position: globalmap.getCenter()});
```

this will listen to right click on the marker;

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker,  'rightclick',  function(mouseEvent) { alert('Right click triggered'); });
```

**EDIT:** Regarding the [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/reference.html) plugin, I can see that it's extending from google.maps.OverlayView, and passes in a marker in the **marker_** property of the object. This means you could still have your way doing (copying from the example):

```
 var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: homeLatLng,
   draggable: true,
   raiseOnDrag: true,
   map: map,
   labelContent: "$425K",
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
 });
```

and then add the right click behaviour as

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1.marker_,  'rightclick',  function(mouseEvent) { alert('Right click triggered'); });
```

Comment: Tried stripping back the code like you suggested. Right click is fired on standard marker. Something must not be working in the markerWithLabel plugin I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

Your last attempt:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.eventDiv_, "rightclick",function(){/**/});
```

...will not work, because there is no `rightclick`-DOMMouseEvent.

You must observe the `click`-event of the `eventDiv_` and check if the `button`-property of the event is set to `2`(when it does a right-click has been detected)

Comment: unfortunately the click event isn't fired when I right click. Google maps steals them..

Comment: Use mouseup instead of click

Answer (score 2):

The rightclick event works on a google.maps.Marker for me:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function() {
    infowindow.setContent("<div style='width:100px'>rightclick</div>");
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_event-simple_rightclick.html)

Comment: yes, but not when I rightclick on the label itself.